# What is the formula of residues from scipy lstsq?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I did a simple least square using the code below. At the end, computing tje residues by hand, I do not obtain the same value as scipy. Thus I wonder how scipy compute the residues ?

```
from scipy.linalg import lstsq
np.random.seed(30042019)
A = np.random.uniform(0, 500, (100, 2))
A = np.hstack((A, np.ones((100, 1))))
B = np.dot(A, [4, 5, -2])
X, residues, rank, s = lstsq(A, B)
print("X = ", X)
print("rank = ", rank)
print("residues = ", residues)
print("calc res =", ((np.dot(A, X) - B) ** 2).mean())
```

Results

```
X =  [ 4.  5. -2.]
rank =  3
residues =  5.43023571273382e-24
calc res = 6.2083782381226065e-25
```

The values of scipy residues and residues compute by hands are different. Is there any link with the rank ?

Comment: I may be mistaken, but given the size of numbers in your input data, wouldn't the size of the residuals be neglible, i.e., effectively 0? The insignificant difference in outputs may then be 'cause SciPy likely computes the residuals along the way, and thus would end up with some different floating point (rounding) errors than your calculation.

Comment: Oh ! Of course ... you are true. I did the calculations with some noise on the point and I got the same results.